# Can't access internet on my kali linux 64bit

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, kali-linux, ip-address

I installed the latest version of kali Linux in virtual box latest version. my internet worked fine for few days but suddenly it stopped working even my virtual machine is connected to internet when I use bridge adapter I could not get IP address but I get IP address when I connect my kali Linux with NAT

Here is my settings:[settings of my network for kali Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fNMR.png)

Here is my output for "ifconfig":[output for ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYoUt.png)

pls help to get it working again.. Thankyou.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score -1):

If the configuration was original by NAT and now you are in Bridge, have you tried to perform a down / up of the interface? Maybe it is not refreshing the configuration.

I understand that the network configuration is not static

Commands:
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0

Comment: sorry still not working... what should i do

Comment: I see that you use the WIFI network interface. Do you have a Wi-Fi connection when using the virtual machine on the host machine? You can also see which is the network configuration that you currently have in the machine. Do you have it by DHCP? What's written in your / etc / network / interfaces file?